# Partial derivative of cost function

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives, partial-derivative

I'm trying to find the derivative of the cost function in respect to m (slope) and b (y-intercept).

Looking for the derivative in respect to slope m and intercept b:

```
d/dm f(m, b) = SUM of (y - m * x + b)^2
d/db f(m, b) = SUM of (y - m * x + b)^2
```

My own approach comes to:

```
d/dm f(m, b) = SUM of 2(0 - (1 * x + 0))
d/db f(m, b) = SUM of 2(0 - (1 + 1))
```

which does seem wrong tho I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong as the code returns incorrect data.

So first step is the derivative of the outer part of function which in case of m comes to `2(y - (mx + b))` the second step is to then evaluated the inner part because in respect to **m** the **y** and **b** are constants so they become 0 and **m** in respect to **m** is 1 so: `2(0 - (1 * x + 0))`

For the second partial derivative in respect to **b** I'm not sure. I do the first step the same way and get `2(y - (mx + b))` than **y** and **mx** are constants in respect to **b** so they are 0 and well **b** in respect to **b** is 1 so I come to the result of `2(0 - (0 + 1))` which however in the end in the code returns incorrect results.

Wolfram alfa:
partial derivative of m in f(m,b) = (y - (m*x + b))^2

tells me that this is the correct result for the partial derivative in respect to **m** is `2x(b + m*x - y)`

Comment: Can you formulate your question in more consistent way? In your first shadowed block there is $y-mx+b$, but further you write $y-(mx+b)$. These expressions are not equal generally. If you need to find derivative, then why do you write derivative as problem statement. Maybe do you mean $f(m,b)=\sum_i (y_i-(mx_i+b))^2$ and you need to find partial derivative of this function? Then you can use the fact that derivative of the sum is equal to the sum of derivatives. And $\partial f/\partial m=\sum_i (-2x_i)(y_i-(mx_i+b))=\sum_i 2x_i(mx_i+b-y_i)$.

Comment: $\frac{d}{dm} (y-(mx+b))^2$ should be taken using chain rule or by expanding square. $\frac{d}{dm} f(m)^2 = 2f(m) f'(m)$, not just $2 f(m)$. If $f(m)=y-(mx+b)$, then $f'(m)=-x$ not 1.

Answer (score 1):

You are starting with an expression of the form:

$\qquad\displaystyle f(m,b)=\sum\limits_{x,y} g(x,y,m,b)^2$ where $g(x,y,m,b)=(y-m\cdot x+b)$

The chain rule for this is basically $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial m}=\sum\dfrac{\partial g^2}{\partial g}\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial m} = \sum 2g\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial m}$

So, the partial derivative with respect to $m$ is:

$\qquad\displaystyle\dfrac{\partial f(m,b)}{\partial m}=\sum\limits_{x,y}2 ~g(x,y,m,b)\,\dfrac{\partial g(x,y,m,b)}{\partial m}$ and $\dfrac{\partial g(x,y,m,b)}{\partial m}=-x$

Thus

$\qquad\displaystyle \dfrac{\partial f(m,b)}{\partial m}=\sum\limits_{x,y} -2x\,(y-m\cdot x+b)$

---

Now try the partial derivative with respect to $b$.